# Bayesian Space State Model using Jags

Tags: r, jags

I am trying to write a  Bayesian space state model for population dynamics, I am inexperienced at this kind of models as a consequence I am making a lot of mistakes, I am getting this error message "  Error in node o[1] Invalid parent values". Searching on the web I've learned that this might be because priors are invalid, but I have tested several prior values, and according to the distribution definitions they seem to be ok. In gamma distributions I have tested using the rate parameter and the scale parameter. I don't know how to get this code to run.  I excuse myself because of this question. Here is the code:

```
o<-c(22.77619, 19.07782, 22.08817, 16.32168, 32.57081, 10.48027, 15.93440, 27.54557, 33.39933)
n<-9
cat(file="pop.din","
model {
  t[1] <- n0
  o[1] ~ dlnorm(t[1],tau.obs)
  for (i in 2:9) {
    v[i] <- t[i-1]+r*t[i-1]*(1-t[i-1]/K) #valor esperado
    t[i] ~ dlnorm(v[i],tau.proc) #t valor verdadero
    o[i] ~ dlnorm(t[i],tau.obs)
  }
  r ~ dunif(0,1)
  K ~ dgamma(0.5,5)
  tau.obs ~ dgamma(1,5)
  tau.proc ~ dgamma(1,5)
  n0 ~ dgamma(1,10)
}")

pop.din.data<-c("o")

#initila values for the parameters stored as a list
inits<-function()list(r=runif(0,1),k=runif(0,1),tau.obs=rgamma(1,0,1),tau.proc=rgamma(1,0,1),n0=rgamma(1,0,1))

params<- c("K","r","n0","tau.obs","tau.proc")

ni <- 10000
nt <- 1
nb <- 5000
nc <- 3
library(jagsUI)
j.model   <- jags (model.file = "pop.din", data = pop.din.data,parameters.to.save = "params",
                             inits = inits,n.chains = 3,n.iter = 10000)
```

Kind regards
Antonela

Comment: As a first pass try letting jags choose the starting values - remove the `inits = inits`. Also does `parameters.to.save = "params"` need to be `parameters.to.save = params`